# ¿Cómo puedo agregarle tabulación a un párrafo completo en C#?

Tags: c#, telegram

He estado investigando como colocar un párrafo completo tabulado con C#. Conseguí tabular con `\t`, sin embargo el problema es que sólo lo aplica a la primera línea del párrafo, el resto del mismo no se tabula. ¿Quisiera saber sí existe algún comando que pueda tabular el párrafo completo? Estoy desarrollando un Bot de Telegram y quiero que los mensajes salgan formateados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este ejemplo como la oración es muy larga, **OLIVARES** pasa a una segunda línea, no obstante no sigue la tabulación que se le colocó al inicio del párrafo.

```
\n\t\tEmitida por: \n\t\t*" + empresa.Nombre
```

¿Tienen alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: los string en C# no tienen un concepto de parrafo. Te estas refiriendo a algun otra cosa?

Comment: Ah ok, no no, me refiero a los string. Pero que pasa cuando los strings son muy largos y quieres tabularlos completos, es decir que no se tabule sólo la primera línea sino todas las líneas subsecuentes. ¿Eso es posible?

Comment: La veo muy difícil en winforms, en WPF tienes el paragraph margin para los richtextbox, lo que estas pidiendo es un textbox poderoso como la hoja de trabajo de word

Comment: los strings son sin formato por defecto, el que pone formato es el que lee el string.. por lo tanto deberias hacerlo a mano, poner los saltos de linea o tabulaciones a mano.

Comment: Entiendo. De todas maneras muchas gracias @gbianchi.

Comment: Ok @Mike, de igual manera como soy nuevo en esto, sólo quería salir de dudas y verificar si existe algo parecido, algún comando, etc. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No hay secuencia de escape o método nativo que te permita hacer eso. lo mas cercano es el formato paragraph de WPF. El tabulado automático como el que ves en word no es en realidad una tabulación, si no un margen que se le aplica a un párrafo entero.

Comment: Comprendo, bueno muchas gracias por tomar un tiempo y responder @Mike.

Comment: Algo que podrias hacer es "formatear" el texto para detectar los saltos de linea y generarlos. para eso tendrias que medir el tamaño de tu textbox y el tamaño de los caracteres en pixeles, puedes usar textrender para eso. y cuando el tamaño del texto sea mas grande que la longitud del texto, entonces partes el texto en diferentes lineas. es un código algo enfadoso, pero tuve que hacer algo similar en un proceso que escribía palabras caracter por caracter y no quería que se viera el desplazamiento de la palabra a la siguiente linea.

Comment: Ah interesante, voy a investigar al respecto para ver si soluciona mi problema,ya que lo que desarrollo es un bot de telegram para realizar notificaciones, entonces dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla del celular, va a tener un máximo de caracteres por línea. Ahí tendría que ver como hacer ese cálculo automático en cada celular.

Comment: busca si la clase textrenderer y el metodo measuretext funcionan en dispositivos mobiles. despues de eso puedes comparar las longitudes del texto y de la caja de texto en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Esta pidiendo algo asi:

```
        String texto = "Linea 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Linea 2" + Environment.NewLine + "Linea 3" + Environment.NewLine;
        String textoTabulado = texto.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "\t");
```

Si la primera línea tambien empezar con un tabulador:

```
        String texto = "Linea 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Linea 2" + Environment.NewLine + "Linea 3" + Environment.NewLine;
        String textoTabulado = "\t" + texto.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "\t");
```

La idea es transformar esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mmm entiendo tu punto, pero no era lo que estaba pidiendo. Lo que quería saber era si por ejemplo `Linea 1` fuera un string muchísimo más largo que no quepa en una sola línea sino en varias líneas. Cuando tabulo este string, sólo tabula la primera linea y las siguientes líneas no se tabulan. Es sólo eso.

Comment: Es verdad Jerson no entendí la pregunta...

Comment: No te preocupes, igual tu respuesta es de ayuda para otros casos específicos como el que hiciste. Muchas gracias.